# How to display individual moves for my Applet?

Tags: java, applet

I am currently making an applet that simulates a Tortoise vs. Hare Race. They each have individual moves, picked at random. My applet works, but it only displays the end of the race in which the Tortoise Wins. I would like it to display the individual moves that the tortoise/hare make, almost like a gif.

heres my code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Project2 extends Applet
{
Image tortoise, hare;
int tortoiseXPos = 180, hareXPos = 180;
final int tortoiseYPos = 50, hareYPos = 400, SQUARE = 20;
int move;

public void init()
{
    tortoise = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "tortoise.gif");
    hare = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "hare.gif");
}

public void gameControl()
{
    //1200 is finish line
    while((tortoiseXPos < 1200) || (hareXPos < 1200))
    {
        move =  (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        tortoiseMoves(move);
        hareMoves(move);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            delay();
        }
    }


}
public void paint(Graphics field)
{
    drawField(field);
    drawMove(field);
    //Display winner when they get to the finish line
    if(tortoiseXPos >= 1200)
    {
            field.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 72));
            field.drawString("Tortoise Wins", 650, 240);
        }
        else if(hareXPos >= 1200)
        {
            field.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 72));
            field.drawString("Tortoise Wins!!", 650, 240);
        }
}   

public void drawField(Graphics field)
{
    setBackground(Color.green);
    Font f  = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 48);
    field.setFont(f);
    field.drawString("Tortoise", 0, 75);
    field.drawString("Hare", 0, 425);

    //fill alternating black and white rectangles       
    field.setColor(Color.black);
    int x = 180;
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        field.fillRect(x, 50, SQUARE, 50);
        field.fillRect(x, 400, SQUARE, 50);
        x += (SQUARE * 2);
    }
    field.setColor(Color.white);
    x = 200;
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        field.fillRect(x, 50, SQUARE, 50);
        field.fillRect(x, 400, SQUARE, 50);
        x += (SQUARE * 2);
    }
}

public void clearMove(Graphics s)
{
}

public void drawMove(Graphics s)
{
    gameControl();
    s.drawImage(tortoise, tortoiseXPos, 50, this);
    s.drawImage(hare, hareXPos, 400, this);

}
public void tortoiseMoves(int move)
{
    //Moves for Tortoise
    if(move <= 5)
    {
        tortoiseXPos += (3 * SQUARE);
    }
    else if(move <= 8)
    {
        tortoiseXPos += SQUARE;
    }
    else if(move <= 10)
    {
        tortoiseXPos -= (6 * SQUARE);
    }

    if(tortoiseXPos < 0)
    {
        tortoiseXPos = 0;
    }

    if(tortoiseXPos > 1200)
    {
        tortoiseXPos = 1200;
    }
}

public void hareMoves(int move)
{
    //Moves for Hare
    if(move <= 2)
    {
        hareXPos += (9 * SQUARE);
    }
    if(move <= 5)
    {
        hareXPos += (SQUARE);
    }
    if(move <= 6)
    {
        hareXPos -= (SQUARE);
    }
    if(move <= 8)
    {
        hareXPos -= (2 * SQUARE);
    }
    if(move <= 10)
    {
        hareXPos = hareXPos;
    }

    if(hareXPos < 0)
    {
        hareXPos = 0;
    }

    if(hareXPos > 1200)
    {
        hareXPos = 1200;
    }
}

public void delay()
{
    //To see individual moves
    for(int i = 0; i <= 90000000; i++)
    {}
}
}
```

If you guys could give me some pointers on what method to use or how I should go about doing this, I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: You always see "Tortoise Wins" because you always draw that string, even when the Hare wins. You need to write "Hare wins" instead, when the hare wins.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks, didn't catch that

Answer (score 1):

Add two arrays to your class and store each move for each racer.  Then, "paint" the points for each racer on the screen as the race is progressing.

Comment: I want them displayed in realtime, not at the very end. So you can see the tortoise and hare moving around on the screen as the applet executes.

Comment: Updated answer based on requirement.  Essentially, draw the points in the arrays before you draw the next move.  You could add a method that takes the array and draws points and then call it in your paint() method.